# AngularJS factory dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

I'm using AngularJS to extract information stored in mongodb. I'm trying to use a factory to retrieve that information using `$http` . I read so much information about how to do it, and no one works for me.

Also I'm using node + express, the routes works fine. The problem is the factory and the dependencies.

The only thing I need is:

1. Extract information stored in mongodb.
2. Store that information in a controller.
3. Show that information in the main page of my app.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="angular-blog">
  <head>
    <title> Angular blog </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- AngularJS and JQuery include.  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/article.css" ></link>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <menu-bar></menu-bar>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="ArticleController as articleCtrl">
      <h2> Blog </h2>
      <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="elem in articleCtrl.list">
        <h4>{{ elem.title }}</h4>
        <p> {{ elem.desc }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Custom controller. -->
    <script src="./js/controllers/article.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**article.js**

```
(function (){
  var app = angular.module ('angular-blog', []);

  app.directive ('menuBar', function (){
    return {
      restrict        : 'E',
      templateUrl     : '../templates/menu-bar.html'
    };
  });

  app.service ('articleFactory', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http){
    this.getAllArticles = function (){
      var deferred        = $q.defer(),
          httpPromise     = $http.get ('/entries');

      httpPromise.success (function (data){
        deferred.resolve (data);
      })
      .error (function (err){
        console.log (err);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }]);

  app.controller ('ArticleController', ['$http', 'articleFactory', function ($http, articleFactory){
    this.article = {}; // Simple article.
    this.list = []; // Article list.

    this.list = articleFactory.getAllArticles()
    .then (function (data){
      return data;
    }, function (err){
      console.error (err);
    });

    this.addArticle = function (){
      $http.post ('/addEntry', this.article)
      .success (function (data){
        console.log (data);
      })
      .error (function (data){
        console.log ('Error: ' + data);
      });

      this.article = {};
    };

    this.resetArticle = function (){
      this.article = {};
    };

  }]);

})();
```

**Error**

My main page doesn't show the list.

Comment: Change `app.factory` to `app.service` and try.

Comment: exactly you cannot bind factory with this :-)

Comment: I change factory to service, and I get other error. Question updated !

Comment: obviously this.list = articleFactory.getAllArticles; is not a valid statement getAllArticals is a function not a variable :) Hope it help

Comment: `You don't need this in  this.articleFactory.getAllArticles()  only call it with  articleFactory.getAllArticles()`

Comment: @JasterTDCClan have you got the solution ? or still in problem ?

Comment: @squiroid Now I don't get any errors, but the main page doesn't show the list. I don't know why ...

Comment: console.log(data) before assigning it to this.list and check your api returning anything or not ...!!

Comment: @squiroid Now I have problems with `index.html` because the list contains all data, but the code I have in main page doesn't show the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81210/discussion-between-jastertdc-clan-and-squiroid).

Comment: http://imgur.com/5Aa2lAw @squiroid .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)**

Change your `factory` to `service` as you are using `this` factory return an object or primitive type not bind with `this`

```
 app.services('articleFactory', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http){
    this.getAllArticles = function (){
      var deferred        = $q.defer(),
          httpPromise     = $http.get ('/entries');

      httpPromise.success (function (data){
        deferred.resolve (data);
      })
      .error (function (err){
        console.log (err);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }]);
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Your controller should be like this:-

```
app.controller ('ArticleController', ['$http', 'articleFactory', function ($http, articleFactory){
    this.article = {}; // Simple article.
    this.list = []; // Article list.

   articleFactory.getAllArticles()
    .then (function (data){
       this.list = data;
    }, function (err){
      console.error (err);
    });

    this.addArticle = function (){
      $http.post ('/addEntry', this.article)
      .success (function (data){
        console.log (data);
      })
      .error (function (data){
        console.log ('Error: ' + data);
      });

      this.article = {};
    };

    this.resetArticle = function (){
      this.article = {};
    };
```

Comment: obviously this.list = articleFactory.getAllArticles; is not a valid statement getAllArticals is a function not a variable :)
Hope you got it.

Comment: I'll change that, and I still get the same problem.

Comment: Now I don't get any error, but my main page doesn't show the list @squiroid.